# Monk ki-focus mechanics

Tags: dnd-4e

So I am playing minotaur monk and have profficiency to use execution axe. 
Now how the whole ki-focus thing works...

What I got from the PH3 is that:

- I can attune myself to a ki-focus and use its enhancement bonus and propereties for my powers and add it to weapon attacks I make with weapons I have proff. with (in my case the e. axe)
- I can use magical weapon as an implement as well, this way I will take its enhancement bonus and critical hit effects, and magic item properties and powers you can apply to that power.

Now I have these questions regarding the mechanics:

1. When I chose my ex. axe as an implement, how will it work since the axe has brutal 2 and high crit? Will the brutal properety carry over to my monk powers? Same goes for criting with it - will the high crit apply as well?
2. Are ki-focuses in a different position than the weapons I can use as an implement? When I have magical weapon +2 and ki-focus +1:

   - can I add the +1 to the +2 of the weapon when making basic melee attack?
   - can I say I use the weapon as an implement and do the same thing (gaining +4)?
   - can I use my monk powers when I wield two handed axe and say I use it as an implement?

(or do monk powers require me to have at least one hand free)

3)Does the Ki-focus increase the damage of my Flury of blows?

- When I want to use magical weapon as an implement, will it work as well?

Hope I listed everything regarding this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to answer your bullets in order:

1. Sort of, but not really. When you use your axe as your implement for your monk powers, you would add any properties related to the axe (such as the enhancement bonus), and any crit effects from the enchantment (usually 1d6 per plus, but often other things. However, brutal and high-crit *only* apply to [W] dice. Implement powers never use the [W] dice and instead use stated damage expressions (like 2d8 or 1d6). So while you get the enhancement and crit effects from the *enchantment* you don't get the effects that affect weapon dice (similar to how you don't get the proficiency bonus when you use it as an implement).

   Essentially, when you use an item as a weapon, all of the weapon properties apply (weapon damage dice, brutal, high crit, reach etc). However, when you use a weapon as an implement, only the enchantment applies. The only real difference between your executioner's axe and a long sword, or even a heavy crossbow in this case is what enchantments can be applied to them. (HT [Oblivious Sage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3548/oblivious-sage) there).
2. They are different item slots, but the bonuses are the same and do not stack. The +1 from a Ki focus is an enhancement bonus, the +2 from the weapon is *also* an enhancement bonus. To answer your bullets directly

   - No. You only get one or the other, not both.
   - You can use the weapon, but you only get +2, the proficiency bonus only counts on Weapon powers. (Note: weapon power via the Ki focus gets the proficiency from the Axe as well)
   - Yes, you can use it as an implement *if* it's an implement power. Pay attention to the power's keywords, some powers are Weapon and some powers are Implement, this matters greatly as it determines whether or not you get to add the proficiency bonus.
   - To address the parenthetical, this is kind of actually complicated. It depends heavily on the power. If the power requires a one handed weapon, you need a one handed weapon. If it doesn't say, then no. However, note that to use your monk unarmed strike, you must have a hand free, so you can't do that while *wielding* your executioner's axe (talk to your DM though, you might be able to hold it in one hand and strike unarmed...whether you can or not is touchy).
3. Is the Flurry of Blows a weapon or implement power? If yes, then you get the enhancement bonus, if no, then you don't. If it's a weapon power you get the proficiency bonus, if its an implement power, then you don't (It's neither, it doesn't even have a to-hit roll...if it *were* a weapon or implement power, you'd be able to add the enhancement bonus to the damage, but it's not so that's moot).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I understand better how this works. Only to clarify the enhancement thing. When the book says that I may "add the enhancement bonus to ... " the adding means overwriting any other enhancement bonuses (and not adding in a mathematical way where I would sum both enhancement values)

Comment: @pppddd yes, enhancement is only ever added once. So +1 or 2+ not both. Again, the basic rule is "same typed bonuses don't stack."

Comment: "[Tradition] Flurry of Blows" is _neither_ a Weapon power _nor_ an Implement power. It is much like the Rogue's Sneak Attack or the Warlock's Warlock's Curse in that it is simply the Monk's source of Striker bonus damage. (Also, there's no attack roll for FoB, so the proficiency bonus would be irrelevant even if it were a Weapon power.)

Comment: Note, though, that Flurry of Blows is still an attack power, so things like Blistering Flourish's bonus, or Claw Gloves + Werebear/wolf/rat theme's f10, do still apply to it, while they wouldn't with Sneak Attack/Warlock's Curse/etc.